# Capturar texto dentro da tag option

Tags: javascript, html

Quero pegar o texto que está dentro da tag `<option>TEXTO</option>`. A situação é a seguinte:

```html
<select xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="page1:form_section:form1:selectListCampus" name="page1:form_section:form1:selectListCampus" class="form-control" size="1" onchange="OnChange_Campus(this);"><option value="">Selecionar uma Opção</option><option value="a0PA0000007bDQ7MAM" selected="selected">Exemplo 1</option><option value="a0PA0000007bDQCMA2">Exemplo 2</option></select>
```

Já tentei `document.getElementById('page1:form_section:form1:selectListCampus').innerText` pra resgatar o texto "Exemplo 1", mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Mas você vai fazer o que com esse valor ?

Comment: Qual `<option>`? Estão aí três...

Comment: Allan, quero guardá-lo em uma variável para guardar no cookie.

Comment: D. Pardal, preciso do "Exemplo 1" e "Exemplo 2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu que pegar o texto da opção selecionada, certo?

Se for isso tente assim:

```
function OnChange_Campus(selectObj){
    var txtOpcao = selectObj.options[selectObj.selectedIndex].text;
    alert(txtOpcao);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para o elemento option selecionado, com JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("id-do-elemento").value
```

Para um elemento específico da lista de options, com JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("id-do-elemento").options[0].value
```

Para o elemento option selecionado, com Jquery:

```
$("#id-do-elemento option:selected").text()
```

Por valor do elemento option, com Jquery:

```
$("#id-do-elemento option[value='value-do-elemento']").text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Penso que `$("#page1:form_section:form1:selectListCampus").text();` te soluciona o problema. Assim é só ir buscar a opção seleccionada e em vez de te retornar a `value`, retorna-te o texto dentro da tag.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso de vária maneiras. Isso depende muito também do que você precisa implementar. Se for só pra armazenar os valores em uma variável o exemplo abaixo demonstra dois casos:

```js
//Criando um id no elemento
var val = document.getElementById('option1').innerText;
console.log(val);
// Iterando a lista
var el = document.querySelector('.form-control');
var elements = [];
for (let n = 0; n < el.length; n++) {
   elements.push(el[n].innerText);            
}
console.log(elements);
```

```html
<select xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="page1:form_section:form1:selectListCampus" name="page1:form_section:form1:selectListCampus" class="form-control" size="1" onchange="OnChange_Campus(this);"><option value="">Selecionar uma Opção</option><option value="a0PA0000007bDQ7MAM" id="option1" selected="selected">Exemplo 1</option><option value="a0PA0000007bDQCMA2">Exemplo 2</option></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o exemplo que consta na API JQuery -
Referência: [JQUERY](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

```js
$(function(){
$( "select" )
  .change(function() {
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str += $( this ).text() + " ";
    });
    $( "div" ).text( str );
  })
  .trigger( "change" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
 id="page1:form_section:form1:selectListCampus" 
 name="page1:form_section:form1:selectListCampus" 
 class="form-control" size="1">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Selecionar uma Opção</option>
  <option value="a0PA0000007bDQ7MAM" >Exemplo 1</option>
  <option value="a0PA0000007bDQCMA2">Exemplo 2</option>
 </select>
 <div></div>
```

Comment: Importar JQuery só para isso? Acho desnecessário.

Comment: @D. Pardal, coloque o teu código para ajudar e não comentários nada necessários